# python application development resources (as in books/online guides)

Tags: python

can anyone recommend a resource (book,tutorial,etc.) that focuses on application development in python?  something similar to Practical Django Projects, but for stand alone applications instead of web apps (for now).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a GUI on your standalone application, you could try [Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt](http://amzn.com/0132354187).  There are other Python reference books of course, but I don't know of any that focus solely on application development without focusing on a particular toolkit (web or otherwise).

Comment: thanks, i came across the book but i was looking for something in GTK, since i'm on Gnome and it seems that GTK is more diffused.  people would have to download the QT library to use an app developed with the QT toolkit no?

i'm currently using django for web apps, i just realized that although i have a decent grasp of the python language, i'm unable to put together a standalone app.

Comment: You can elect to distribute whatever toolkit you use with your app.  For systems with package managers you might just create a package with the proper dependencies, but either way your choice of toolkit won't especially matter - some people will have that toolkit already, and some won't.